# Since iOS 9 I cannot get the Wireless SSID anymore: CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo won't work

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9

Since iOS 9 I cannot get the Wireless SSID anymore. I used to be able to do it but Apple has deprecated the use of `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo`.

Any idea on how I can get it in iOS 9?

Comment: Hot topic at the moment. So far no solution other than to apply for access to the new Network Extension API. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11807

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9 GM it appears this is enabled again. In fact, it's not even listed as deprecated in the online documentation, however the CaptiveNetwork header file does have the following:

```
CNCopySupportedInterfaces (void) __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED_MSG(__MAC_10_8, __MAC_NA, __IPHONE_4_1, __IPHONE_9_0, CN_DEPRECATION_NOTICE);
```

So, it is working in iOS 9 GM for now, but unclear for how long.

Comment: Thanks. So did they re-add it as too many developer complained about it? Any official statement on this in some Apple Developer forum?